Powershell version of cut -d is very slow on large files, am I missing the fast way to do it?
I have a very large (>100k lines) file that i want to split on :.
I then want to discard the first item, and leave all the rest. for example, foo:bar:baz becomes bar:baz.
If i do cut -d ':' -f2- myfile.txt > newfile.txt it finishes in a matter of milliseconds.
I have tried a few methods in Powershell, but I have yet to see one finish. After a couple of minutes I abort, because this script cannot afford to wait that long. Surely there is a better/faster way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.
The most promising method I found so far looks like this:
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("myfile.txt")
try {
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        $split = $line.Split(":")
        $join = $split[1..($split.Length-1)] -join ":"
        Add-Content -Path "newfile.txt" -Value "$join"
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}

Please help/advise.

Looks like you're looking to exclude the first token of a string split in :, i.e.: foo:bar:baz into bar:baz is that correct? If so this method you're using is very inefficient

Yes, that is what I'm trying to do. I edited the question to make that a bit clearer. I am very well aware that it is inefficient, I just can't for the life of me figure out how to properly do it.

100K lines shouldn't be a problem. Try something simpler, like Get-Content myfile.txt |ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^[^:]+:' } |Set-Content newfile.txt

In both examples in this answer you can use regex instead of splitting, it would be more efficient that way. For the regex details you can check: https://regex101.com/r/iGfHWp/1.

If you can read all file content at once, then you can do:

(Get-Content myfile.txt -Raw) -replace '(?m)^.+?:' |
    Set-Content newfile.txt


If you can't read all file content at once and need lowest memory usage possible but still keep it efficient then I'd recommend File.ReadLines + StreamWriter:

try {
    # use absolute path always in this case, i.e.:
    # `newfile.txt` should be `X:\path\to\newfile.txt`
    $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] 'newfile.txt'
    $re = [regex]::new(
        '^.+?:', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled)

    foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('myfile.txt')) {
        $writer.WriteLine($re.Replace($line, ''))
    }
}
finally {
    if ($writer) {
        $writer.Dispose()
    }
}


Reading the whole file is not a problem. The first one seems to work great, it finishes near instantly. I do feel a bit confused about the replace, does omitting a replacement value just imply that it's an empty one?

@Adriaantje by omitting you mean there is no , '' in -replace '(?m)^.+?:' right? if so, yes, if you omit the 2nd argument it will just use an empty string

Santiago's helpful answer demonstrates the best-performing solutions.
As for what you tried:

The primary reason for your command's poor performance is that you called Add-Content in each every loop iteration, necessitating instantiating the .NET class implementing the cmdlet, opening and closing the file for each and every line being processed.

Instead, use the pipeline to stream all output to a single call to Set-Content, or pass all collected output by argument to the -Value parameter.


Your use of the .Split() method with subsequent array manipulation is somewhat inefficient too, and can be replaced with a single call to the -split operator, which allows limiting the number of tokens returned; specifically, 'foo:bar:baz' -split ':', 2 returns only 2 tokens: the first :-separated token ('foo') and the rest of the input string, even if further : instances are present ('bar:baz').


To put it all together, in the form of a line-by-line solution that uses PowerShell-native commands and operators only:
Set-Content newfile.txt -Value (
  (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 myfile.txt).
    ForEach({ $null, $rest = $_ -split ':', 2; $rest })
)

Note that the solution is optimized for performance at the expense of memory usage:

The Get-Content command reads all lines into an array in memory at once, using -ReadCount 0, which is much faster than the default behavior of streaming the lines, one by one.

The intrinsic .ForEach() method is used as the faster alternative to the ForEach-Object cmdlet.

The array of transformed lines is passed by argument to Set-Content, which is faster than by enumeration via the pipeline.



If performance weren't a concern, you could more elegantly - and with less memory usage - write:
Get-Content myfile.txt |
 ForEach-Object { $null, $rest = $_ -split ':', 2; $rest } |
 Set-Content newfile.txt

While object-by-object streaming in the pipeline is intrinsically slower than operating on an array in memory, note that the poor performance of this solution is primarily owed to problems that could be fixed:

Get-Content's line-by-line streaming is notoriously slow, because it decorates each line read with ETS (Extended Type System) properties (e.g. .PSPath), which is expensive; these properties are typically not needed.

As of PowerShell (Core) 7 v7.5.0, there is no opt-out of this decoration; GitHub issue #7537 is the relevant feature request, in response to which implementing a -NoExtendedMember switch has been green-lit, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet.

More generally, even the act of decorating itself could be made much faster, by providing the properties at the type (class) level with lazy (on-demand) value retrieval, as proposed in GitHub issue #7501, which was green-lit as an experimental feature (meaning that it may or may not become an official feature, depending on feedback); unfortunately, activity has stalled.



Both ForEach-Object and Where-Object are slower than they should be, as discussed in GitHub issue #10982.

Unfortunately, a proper fix would be nontrivial, and it doesn't seem to be forthcoming.

A - non-obvious - workaround is to directly call a script block ({ ... }) with a nested process script block in lieu of ForEach-Object (and can you can emulate Where-Object by using conditional in the script block); the following sample commands, which are functionally equivalent, demonstrate the difference in performance; they each process 1 million numbers in the pipeline, adding 1 to each input number:
# SLOW, due to use of ForEach-Object
(Measure-Command {
  $null = 1..1e6 | ForEach-Object { $_ + 1 }
}).TotalSeconds

# MUCH FASTER, due to workaround.
# NOTE:
#  & executes the script block in a *child* scope.
#  If you want to run directly in the caller's scope, use .
#  (dot-sourcing), though note that it is slightly slower.
(Measure-Command {
  $null = 1..1e6 | & { process { $_ + 1 } }
}).TotalSeconds


In Windows PowerShell on my Windows 11 machine, the workaround is about 4 times as fast the ForEach-Object call.






Another method that uses ReadOnlySpan to avoid allocating new memory in the loop. It gets the span to be printed and output that directly into the file
$content = Get-Content myfile.txt -Raw

[char]$delim = [char]':'

# AsSpan doesn't work at the moment, probably it needs some new powershell feature
$memory = [MemoryExtensions]::AsMemory($content)

# Open a StreamWriter to write output
$outputFilePath = "newfile.txt"
$streamWriter = [IO.StreamWriter]::new($outputFilePath, $false)

try {
    [int]$startOfLine = 0

    do {
        [int]$delimiterIndex = $content.IndexOf($delim, $startOfLine)
        if ($delimiterIndex -eq -1) {
            break
        }
        [int]$startIndex = $delimiterIndex + 1

        # Find the end of line
        [int]$newlineIndex = $content.IndexOf([char]"`n", $startIndex)
        if ($newlineIndex -eq -1) {     # Last line
            $newlineIndex = $content.Length
        }

        $startOfLine = $newlineIndex + 1
        $streamWriter.Write($memory.Slice($startIndex, $startOfLine - $startIndex))
    } while ($startOfLine -lt $content.Length)
} finally {
    $streamWriter.Close()
}

